# Cant use grailsApplication.getMetadata.get(" ") while performing unit test for controller in grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit4, grails-controller

In my grails application, in the controller, I use following kind of a thing :

```
class SampleController {
   def action1 = {
     def abc = grailsApplication.getMetadata().get("xyz")
     render abc.toString()
   }
}
```

While running the app, it correctly reads the property "xyz" from application.properties and works fine. But when I write a unit test case for the above controller as follows :

```
class SampleControllerTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {
  SampleController controller

  protected void setUp() {
    super.setUp()
    controller = new SampleController()
    mockController(SampleController)
    mockLogging(SampleController)
  }

  void testAction1() {
    controller.action1()
    assertEquals "abc", controller.response.contentAsString
  }
}
```

But when I do "grails test-app", I expect that it will pick up the property "xyz" from application.properties and will return as expected. But it gives error as "No such property : grailsApplication".

I understand, I guess I need to mock `grailsApplication` object and I tried many of the options also But all those didn't work.

I am new to Grails.

Comment: Witch version of grails are you using?

Comment: version : grails 1.3.7

Comment: You might want to consider injecting the value of abc into your controller instead, that would free your controller from the explicit dependency of grailsApplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mockController` will not mock the `GrailsApplication`, you will need to do it yourself.

The fastest solution would be something like:

```
protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        mockLogging(DummyController)
        GrailsApplication grailsApplication = new DefaultGrailsApplication()
        controller.metaClass.getGrailsApplication = { -> grailsApplication }
    }
```

This solution is not perfect - it will create a new `DefaultGrailsApplication` during each setup and `mockController` also creates some additional instances of `DefaultGrailsApplication`.

Note that you do not need to call `mockController` by yourself it will be done by the `ControllerUnitTestCase` for you.

Comment: Thanks drorb. I tried out the solution you have provided and works exactly as expected.  Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!! :)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :-). If you can, please mark this question as answered - thanks